# Calculate and show the Height Of div after being dragged to y axis in a main div

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am dragging a div within a main div with respect to y-axis.

```
$("#childdiv").draggable({axis:'y'});
```

Now On being dragged vertically , I want to show the position of the draggable component with respect to main div 
For Eg: If object dragged to bottom of the main div . It should say 0px . If dragged to top most part of main div , than it should say so and so px(equal to height of main div)

I tried showing top values like

`$(".draggable-class").css("top")` in `drag` method of `draggable`. It shows all wrong top values .

I am stuck with this . Is there any method to achieve this thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using `$(this).position().top;`